# issue with running dotnet core webapi project

Tags: asp.net-core, port, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-cli

created sample project using "dotnet new webapi" command, then removed Properties/launchSettings.json(to understand what happens if this file is not present). On running the project using "dotnet run" command, the project runs, but on accessing the url - https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html, i get HTTP ERROR 404. But if i run the same project in debug mode(hit f5), i get the swagger page. No change in code or settings was done, while running through "dotnet run" or f5, no error received while "dotnet run". Not able to understand the following:

- why 2 different behaviors when running the code using above steps
- the reason i removed launchsettings.json was to identify, which other setting forces the use of port 5000/5001 and protocol http/https.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the behavior you're observing. An ASP.NET Core project created from scratch listens to [`5000` and `5001` ports](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Infrastructure/Constants.cs#L15-L20) by default even without `launchSettings.json`.

That said, you have a couple of options to set which addresses an ASP.NET Core app will listen to:

From Andrew Lock's [article](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/). Also from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> - `UseUrls()` Set the URLs to use statically in `Program.cs`
> - Environment variables - Set the URLs using `DOTNET_URLS` or `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.
> - Command line arguments - Set the URLs with the `--urls` parameter when running from the command line.
> - Using `launchSettings.json` - Set the URLs using the `applicationUrl` property.
> - `KestrelServerOptions.Listen()` - Configure addresses for Kestrel server manually using `Listen()`.

[`dotnet run` command checks `launchSettings.json` for configuration](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/a30e465a2e2ea4e2550f319a2dc088daaafe5649/src/Cli/dotnet/commands/dotnet-run/RunCommand.cs#L42), if it doesn't find anything, it tries a couple more things before letting Kestrel use its [default ports `:5000` and `:5001`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/Internal/Infrastructure/Constants.cs#L15-L20) for http and https respectively.